# Python 3.4 Can you sum a list but leave some variables out?

Tags: python, sum, python-3.4

I want to take a list and add the last few variable together but skip out the first 2.
ex.
myList = ['bob', 'rocks', '45','56','67']
I have a whole text document that looks like this and I want to take the numbers and add them together for an average but not touch the words.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want to sum all numbers representing items. You can use generator expression like this:

```
sum(int(x) for x in myList if x.isdigit())
```

Comment: generator comprehension to be exact. It does not create a list, just yields elements to `sum` one by one.

Answer (score 0):

use `slicing` to skip the first two entries, and use `map` to cast to `int`:

```
>>> myList = ['bob', 'rocks', '45','56','67']
>>> sum(map(int,myList[2:]))
168
```

Comment: Rather than hardcoding the positions of the words, it's probably better to use an approach that can deal with any combination of words and numbers.

Comment: maybe, maybe not. I understood the position is always the same - if that's not the case, the other solutions work better of course.

Answer (score 0):

can use `.isdigit()` to check if current element is a string or number

```
sum = 0
for each in lines:
    if each.isdigit(): 
       sum +=int(each)
    else:
        print "slipped",each
print sum
```